# How to handle Transaction in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel version 5.2.31. I have structured code in CircuitController, and CircuitService in order to reuse some functions like what should be done in Java.

1. CircuitController:

   `public function pickingAtCarton(Request $request){
       $circuitService = new CircuitService();
       // Do some business here
       $circuitService->completeCircuit($circuit_id);
       $circuitService->completeBoxAtCircuit($circuit_id);
   }`

2.CircuitService:

```
public function completeCircuit($circuit_id, $user){
    $circuit = Circuit::find($circuit_id);
    $circuit->status = Config::get('constants.status.tour.completed');
    $circuit->pick_by = Auth::user();
    $circuit->complete_time=Carbon::now();
    //update complete time later.
    $circuit->save();
}

public function completeBoxAtCircuit($circuit_id, $user){
        DB::table('box_at_circuit')
            ->where('circuit_id', $circuit_id)
            ->update(['status'=> Config::get('constants.status.tour.completed')]);
    }
```

How can i make those 2 methods worked in a transaction?

**Edited the solution based on help from @Luís Ferreira**

The code in CircuitController need to be updated as following:

```
public function pickingAtCarton(Request $request) {
   DB::transaction(function ($request) use ($request) {
      $circuitService = new CircuitService();
      // Do some business here
      $circuitService->completeCircuit($circuit_id);
      $circuitService->completeBoxAtCircuit($circuit_id);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose them on the transaction function from Laravel:

```
public function pickingAtCarton(Request $request) {
   DB::transaction(function () {
      $circuitService = new CircuitService();
      // Do some business here
      $circuitService->completeCircuit($circuit_id);
      $circuitService->completeBoxAtCircuit($circuit_id);
   });
}
```

More information here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#database-transactions